# How to disable active filter in magento2 admin panel

Tags: magento2

[image]

When I am login magento2 Admin panel it showing previous login search result. But I don't want this. I want to turn off or disable this function. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom extension and logically manage this using event observers. Whatever data we are filtering is saved in ui_bookmark table. So whenever you are login again, you can clear this table.

You can create following 2 files.

> etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="admin_user_authenticate_after">
        <observer name="clear_ui_bookmarks" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ClearUiBookmarks" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Observer/ClearUiBookmarks.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ClearUiBookmarks implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Ui\Model\Bookmark $bookmark
    ) {
        $this->bookmark = $bookmark;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $connection = $this->bookmark->getCollection()->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->bookmark->getCollection()->getMainTable();
        $connection->truncateTable($tableName);
    }
}
```

Replace Vendor and Module with your original extension vendor and module name. This way you can achieve your desired result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You  _Yash Shah_

Comment: You're welcome, Please accept the answer if it worked for you !!!